# Shorten Tremolo Beam Length in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, tremolo

I have a simple tremolo, as the picture below shows. The beam lengths are too long and collide with the note heads. How can I adjust the length of the beams to shorten them a bit? I have tried putting a `\override Beam.gap = #1.5` before the `\repeat tremolo ...` part, but it didn't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained here https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/snippets/repeats_003a-engraving-tremolos-with-floating-beams the gap of the tremolo beams can be configured by overriding `Beam.gap`. The default of Beam.gap is 0.8, so try setting it to something higher?

But what bugs me is that this should not be happening by default, and in fact if I do

```
\paper {
  ragged-last = ##f
}

\repeat tremolo 8 { <f' fis'>16 g' }
```

in current stable (2.24) I do get the expected result. This does raise two points for me:

1. Do you perhaps use an outdated version of Lilypond?
2. If not, can you post an example where this happens, so we can analyze why this happens in the first place and eventually fix it?

Comment: The problem solved, I needed only bigger values to make the beam gap appear on the score.

Comment: @Student But it still does not answer the question why this is happening in the first place. This should not require a manual intervention.